# Почему Java на Ubuntu не может загрузить Main class?

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, intellij-idea, jar

Делаю JavaFX GUI. На windows работает, но на Linix'е выдаёт:

```
java -jar MyFxApp.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.superpuperdeveloper.fx.test.Main
```

Хотя в Jar'нике всё есть. [Вот сам Jar.](https://yadi.sk/d/M00hamLB3SzuJm). [Исходный код](https://hastebin.com/udiwawabez.scala).

Comment: [Справка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) пишет, что файл манифеста должен заканчиваться переводом строки. Попробуйте убрать лишние переводы строк в манифесте и оставить только один после строки с Main-Class. (Пробелы после пути класса тоже уберите, если они есть).

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030675/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-with-a-jar-file) похожий вопрос. Посмотрите, может что-то из предложенного поможет.

Comment: Зашибись, теперь и на винде не работает

Comment: Попробуйте запустить так: java -cp .; MyFxApp.jar ru.timofeheus.fx.test.Main Заработает?

Answer (score 2):

`Main` класс не должен быть расширением чего либо. Используйте следующую структуру:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(App.class, args);
    }
}

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Было не лень декомпилировать?)

Comment: Этого делать не пришлось, т.к. по вопросу понял (была такая же ситуация в прошлом году)

Comment: Наверное не очень корректно оставлять мне уже скомпилированный Jar архив. Вот исходник Main.java: https://hastebin.com/udiwawabez.scala